# How to return a string from java project into android project

Tags: java, android

I tried many times to return a string from java project to an android project
But it keeps sending incorrect values as in 2 as it should be 1 here is an example.

Java Project:

```
public static String getString(){
if(string.equals("1")){
return "1"
}else{
return "2"
}
}
```

Android Project:

```
JavaProject.getString();
```

and in the android project it returns 2 as it should be 1

So what should i do?
Thanks for all...

Comment: What is the value id string? Can you post whole codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fyou dont pass string as value,
    string.equals("1")
will always return false, pas a value to your method
    public static String getString(string){
    if(string.equals("1")){
    return "1"
    }else{
    return "2"
    }
    }

and call it either getString("1") or getString("2")

Comment: I meant like that , Let me explain again.                             boolean somethingboolean = false;                                if(something == "1"){somethingboolean = true}                                  public static String getString(){if(somethingboolean == true){ return "1" }else{ return "2"} }